# Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$, $[G:H] = p$ is prime and $a \in H$.

Tags: group-theory

In my group theory course, I came across the following lemma which confuses me:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$, $[G:H] =p$ is 
>   prime and $a \in H$. Then one of two cases applies:
>
> 1) $C_H(a) \neq C_G(a)$. This means that the conjugacy class of $a$ in
>   $H$ is the same as the conjugacy class of $a$ in $G$.
>
> 2) $C_H(a) = C_G(a)$. This means that the conjugacy class of $a$ in
>   $G$ is a disjoint union of $p$ conjugacy classes of $a$ in $H$.

What does it mean in case 2, when it says that "This means that the conjugacy class of $a \in H$ is a disjoint union of $p$ conjugacy classes of $a$ in $H$"?

I was under the impression that the there is only one conjugacy class for each element. So why does it say the union of $p$ conjugacy classes of $a$?

Comment: are you sure it doesn't just say it is the disjoint union of $p$ conjugacy classes?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Unless I made a mistake in writing down my notes ... hmm

Comment: because that would be true